# Extracting information from the certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, biginteger

I am working on client authentication(in a sample JSP application) using certificates.
I have written a code to extract the client information from the client certificate. Now I wanted to use certificate's serial number to identify the particular use from the database.

I extract the serial number using 
    <%= cert.getSerialNumber %>
It gives me an output 3. Is this a integer, BigInteger or array value?

Is there any way I can declare this as an another integer variable for example int a = (serial number value)?? I have not played much with jsp so I do not know exactly where to have a code for that in my jsp file.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks in advance. I am attaching my code which extracts the serial number from the certificate installed.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.math.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<center> <font color="red"> Welcome</font> </center>
<%
Object o = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
if (o != null) {
X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[]) o;
X509Certificate cert = certs[0];
%>   
<%= cert.getSerialNumber() %>             
<%   
}   
else {
%>
You are not Authorized!
Your certificate cannot be found!
<%
}
%>
<br><br>
<form method = "post" action = "page2.jsp">
<input type = submit value = "click me">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getSerialNumber()` method returns a `BigInteger` object, according to the [X509Certificate API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/security/cert/X509Certificate.html). If you want to assign this value to a variable, you can simply do:

```
BigInteger serialNumber = cert.getSerialNumber();
```

On a side note, this really has nothing to do with JSP knowledge, this is core Java.